# Classcastexception with spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-ldap

We are changing our ldap from the java ldap library to spring's to take advantage of the rollback.  It mostly works.  Mostly.

One of our problems is that whenever an exception is thrown, instead of the exception bubbling out, we get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager$ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionObject incompatible with org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doSetRollbackOnly(HibernateTransactionManager.java:696) ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:852) ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822) ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410) ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114) ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
```

This swallows up the exceptions.  Yet, it doesn't seem to prevent the rollback from actually happening.

Relevant parts of our spring config:

```
<ldap:context-source
          url="${LDAP_URL_SSL}"
          base="${SEARCHBASE_DC}"
          referral="follow"
          authentication-source-ref="afmsAuthenticationSource" />
<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" />
<bean id="txManager" name="txManager transactionManager" class="my.package.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="enoteSessionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultUserName" value="umc.not.provided" />
    <property name="defaultApplicationId" value="umc" /> 
</bean> 
<ldap:transaction-manager id="ldapTransactionManager" session-factory-ref="sessionFactory" >
       <ldap:default-renaming-strategy />
</ldap:transaction-manager>
```

What you'll notice is that we have both a hibernate transaction manager (which we customized a long time ago and has worked forever) and the new contextsource transaction manager.  Both are invoked via either AOP or @Transactional depending on which part of the code one is in.

We have a little disagreement in house as to whether we are supposed to REPLACE the existing tx manager with the ldap one (which might do both jobs) or ADD TO it.  The dev doing the work thinks ADD TO.  I think REPLACE, and i think this exception is a symptom of having both in play.

Anyway, can someone give advice on what might be causing this exception, and whether having one or both tx manager is the right way to use this library?